# Strange iframe added into body tags called `rufous-sandbox`

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm working on a local WordPress site, and for some reason there is an `iframe` added just after the opening `body` tag which makes the body to drop down about 20px.

Google only returned 1 relevant result when searching for it, and what I read there didn't help much. It can be found [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/my-meny-is-jumping-down?replies=7).

The WordPress site has no plugins installed, and setting it to `display: none;` doesn't work.

Here's a screenshot from Chrome so you can see it:

[image]

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It seems like it is added by the Twitter script. If you remove it the iframe will disappear.
It sure looks like you have the Twitter plugin installed in some way or the other as you can see it says data-twttr-rendered="true" in the body tag.

If you remove the code - in my case the code below - it will disappear

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    var twitterWidgets = document.createElement('script');
    twitterWidgets.type = 'text/javascript';
    twitterWidgets.async = true;
    twitterWidgets.src = '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(twitterWidgets);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Deleting the javascript, the widget doesn't display.

Comment: That's correct @Aerendir - I'm merely trying to explain why this iframe appears.